# How to preload polygon in Google DrawingManager by passing predefined coordinates

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I am using `@react-google-maps/api` to use google-maps in my react.js application, and I am using its different components. Now, I want to draw a polygon in Google DrawingManager using predefined polygons. How do I go about it?

```
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { DrawingManager } from "@react-google-maps/api";
export const libraries = ["geometry", "places", "drawing"];

function MyComponent({
  setPolygons,
  plottedPolygons,
  operationType,
  drawingEnabled,
  setDrawingEnabled,
}) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(6);
  const [shape, setShape] = useState(null);
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 23, lng: 54 });
 

  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "script-loader",
    googleMapsApiKey: "key",
    language: "en",
    region: "us",
    libraries: libraries,
  });

  const onPolygonComplete = (polygon) => {
    // Handle completed polygon
    setDrawingEnabled(false);
    const paths = polygon
      .getPath()
      .getArray()
      .map((point) => ({
        lat: point.lat(),
        lng: point.lng(),
      }));

    // Make the polygon editable
    polygon.setOptions({
      draggable: false,
      editable: true,
    });

    // Listen for polygon edits
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "set_at", () => {
      handlePolygonEdit(polygon.getPath().getArray());
    });
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "insert_at", () => {
      handlePolygonEdit(polygon.getPath().getArray());
    });
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), "remove_at", () => {
      handlePolygonEdit(polygon.getPath().getArray());
    });

    setPolygons(paths);
    //center map on polygon
    const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    polygon.getPath().forEach((element) => {
      bounds.extend(element);
    });
    mapRef.current.fitBounds(bounds);
    setZoom(mapRef.current.getZoom());
  };

  const handlePolygonEdit = (updatedPaths) => {
    const paths = updatedPaths.map((point) => ({
      lat: point.lat(),
      lng: point.lng(),
    }));
    console.log("Updated Polygon Paths:", paths);
    setPolygons(paths);
  };

  const onUnmount = useCallback(() => {
    mapRef.current = null;
  }, []);

  // const handleOnLoad = (map) => (mapRef.current = map);
  const handleOnLoad = (map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;

    // If in "edit" mode and there are plottedPolygons, fit bounds to show the polygon
    if (operationType === "edit" && plottedPolygons.length > 0) {
      const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      plottedPolygons.forEach((polygon) => {
        polygon.forEach((point) => {
          bounds.extend(point);
        });
      });
      mapRef.current.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  };
  const drawingManagerRef = useRef(null);



  return (
    <>
      {isLoaded ? (
       
                  
                  <GoogleMap
                    key="google-map"
                    ref={mapRef}
                    mapContainerClassName="App-map"
                    zoom={zoom}
                    version="weekly"
                    mapContainerStyle={{
                      width: "100%",
                      height: "500px",
                    }}
                    options={{
                      gestureHandling: "greedy",
                      disableDefaultUI: true,
                      keyboardShortcuts: false,
                    }}
                    center={center}
                    onLoad={handleOnLoad}
                    onUnmount={onUnmount}
                  >
                    <DrawingManager
                      ref={drawingManagerRef}
                      onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
                      onOverlayComplete={(e) => {
                        setShape(e.overlay);
                      }}
                      options={{
                        drawingMode:
                          drawingEnabled && operationType === "add"
                            ? "polygon"
                            : null,

                        // drawingMode: drawingEnabled ? "polygon" : null,
                        drawingControl: drawingEnabled,
                        drawingControlOptions: {
                          position:
                            window.google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER,
                          drawingModes: ["polygon"],
                        },
                        markerOptions: {
                          draggable: false,
                        },

                        polylineOptions: {
                          editable: true,
                          draggable: false,
                        },
                        rectangleOptions: {
                          editable: true,
                          draggable: false,
                        },
                        circleOptions: {
                          editable: true,
                          draggable: false,
                        },

                        polygonOptions: {
                          editable: operationType === "edit", // Set to true only in edit mode
                          draggable: false,
                          fillOpacity: 0.5,
                          strokeWeight: 2,
                          strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                          zIndex: 999,
                          paths:
                            plottedPolygons.length > 0
                              ? plottedPolygons[0]
                              : [],
                        },
                      }}
                    />

                   
                  </GoogleMap>
               
      ) : (
        <div>loading</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default MyComponent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `<Polygon/>` component instead of the `<DrawingManager/>` for pre-loaded points

The official API documentation is clear about the purpose of the `DrawingManager` class, which is to,

> *"provide graphical interface **for users to draw**
> polygons, rectangles, polylines, circles, and markers on the map."*

The purpose of the `DrawingManager` is for the users to "manually" draw different kind of objects on the map. If you want to load a polygon with already existing data without the users having to draw them, the Google Maps API already had the [Polygon objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons).

If your goal is to make it **editable** even after rendering, then you can just set the `editable` property of the `PolylineOptions` to `true`. As this will enable the user to edit the shape by dragging the control points shown at the vertices and on each segment. Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolylineOptions.editable

In your case, since you are using the `react-google-maps/api` library, you can use the `<Polyline/>` component. The library supports the `editable` property so you should not have any issues implementing this.

It should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Polyline } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const containerStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh",
};

samplePolygon = [
  { lat: -3.746341, lng: -38.561108 },
  { lat: -3.742494, lng: -38.607967 },
  { lat: -3.81688, lng: -38.609995 },
  { lat: -3.815362, lng: -38.493357 },
  { lat: -3.746341, lng: -38.561108 },
];

const center = {
  lat: -3.775,
  lng: -38.55,
};

const zoom = 12;

function MyComponent() {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: "google-map-script",
    googleMapsApiKey: "API_KEY_HERE",
  });

  const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null);

  const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setMap(map);
  }, []);

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setMap(null);
  }, []);

  return isLoaded ? (
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
      center={center}
      zoom={zoom}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      onUnmount={onUnmount}
    >
      <Polyline
        onLoad={() => {
          alert("Polyline Loaded");
        }}
        editable={true}
        path={samplePolygon}
      />
      <></>
    </GoogleMap>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
}

export default React.memo(MyComponent);
```

Here's a proof of concept codesandbox: [Editable Polygon](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/polygon-forked-nv5k4n?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900063b6h73h87i63%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi800023b6haa9fgg52%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900033b6hme0uwi7t%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900053b6hy347w2v1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clreemyi800023b6haa9fgg52%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi800023b6haa9fgg52%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrehike000023b6hhtf92era%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A45%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A15%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A45%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A15%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrehike000023b6hhtf92era%2522%257D%252C%2522clreemyi900053b6hy347w2v1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900053b6hy347w2v1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900043b6htf5l1rqn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900043b6htf5l1rqn%2522%257D%252C%2522clreemyi900033b6hme0uwi7t%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clreemyi900033b6hme0uwi7t%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

> NOTE: Use your own API Key